# Cloudformation API GW IntegrationResponse/response headers

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

It is possible to use !Ref to a S3 bucket to use within a ResponseParameter.  For example:

```
IntegrationResponses:
      - ResponseParameters:
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'https://dynamicbucketname.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "'true'"

S3Bucket:
 Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
 Properties:
   PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
     BlockPublicAcls: true
     IgnorePublicAcls: false
     BlockPublicPolicy: true
     RestrictPublicBuckets: true  
   WebsiteConfiguration:
     IndexDocument: index.html
     ErrorDocument: error.html
```

So essentially I'm using a resource AWS::S3::Bucket which allows the template to create the bucket.  Hence the name will be dynamic.  I want to be able to !Ref S3Bucket within the Origin.  Is that even possible?  I know it can be static like "'https://www.example.com'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to this as follows using [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) function:

It is possible to use !Ref to a S3 bucket to use within a ResponseParameter. For example:

```
IntegrationResponses:
      - ResponseParameters:
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: !Sub "'https://${S3Bucket.DomainName}'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "'true'"
```

Other `Bucket` return values than `DomainName` are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#aws-properties-s3-bucket-return-values):

Comment: Hmm maybe I have to escape it but it doesn't actually give me the variable I need.  It gives me Access-Control-Allow-Origin '{S3Bucket}'

Comment: @mcgoosh Sorry. My mistake. It should be: `!Sub "'https://${S3Bucket}.s3-${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'"`

Comment: @mcgoosh This form is even shorter: `!Sub "'https://${S3Bucket.DomainName}'"`